# how to update prophet model with new data added to the old data set? I tried the tutorial but I get errors

Tags: python, time-series, predict, forecast, facebook-prophet

So I tried the one in FbProphet tutorial website:

https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/additional_topics.html#updating-fitted-models

I got this error: **RuntimeError: mismatch in dimension declared and found in context; processing stage=initialization; variable name=beta; position=0; dims declared=(14); dims found=(49)**

Even though the updated data frame is the same as the old one, just few more rows.

I also tried what was told here: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/46

Same error. I tried the following:

m = Prophet(interval_width=0.95, weekly_seasonality=True, daily_seasonality=True, yearly_seasonality=True)

m.fit(df)

m2 = Prophet(interval_width=0.95, weekly_seasonality=True, daily_seasonality=True, yearly_seasonality=True)

model2 = m2.fit(df_and2Days,init=m.params)

I got a new error: **RuntimeError: mismatch in number dimensions declared and found in context; processing stage=initialization; variable name=k; dims declared=(); dims found=(1,1)**

It seems like it's a dimension problem, any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SI found where is the problem. I was identifying variables for the main model `m1` and I didn't do the same for `m2`. Meaning: the `interval_width=0.95`, `weekly_seasonality=True`, `daily_seasonality=True`, `yearly_seasonality=True` and the holidays, so the right code should be like this:

```
m1 = Prophet(interval_width=0.95, weekly_seasonality=True, daily_seasonality=True, yearly_seasonality=True)

m1.add_country_holidays(country_name='USA')

m1.fit(df)

m2 = Prophet(interval_width=0.95, weekly_seasonality=True, daily_seasonality=True, yearly_seasonality=True)

m2.add_country_holidays(country_name='USA')

model2 = m2.fit(df_and2Days,init=m.params)
```

This should work just fine, and it makes sense. When you define variables in the first model and you don't define the same variables in the second model you will end up with mismatch for sure!